# MIPS Linux assembler code understanding about load byte

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, mips, mips32, disassembly

I have the following question here

I need to understand the following MIPS disassembling code:

```
.text:00489060             la      $v0, 0x4D0000

.text:00489064             la      $v0, 0x4D0000

.text:00489068             addiu   $v1, $v0, (aBig5 - 0x4D0000)  # "BIG-5"

.text:0048906C             lw      $v0, (aBig5 - 0x4D0000)($v0)  # "BIG-5"

.text:00489070             lbu     $a0, (aBig5+5 - 0x4D6A68)($v1)

.text:00489074             lbu     $v1, (aBig5+4 - 0x4D6A68)($v1)

.text:00489078             swl     $v0, 0($s1)

.text:0048907C             swr     $v0, 3($s1)

.text:00489080             sb      $a0, 5($s1)

.text:00489084             b       loc_48A190

.text:00489088             sb      $v1, 4($s1)

.text:0048908C  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

.text:0048908C

.text:0048908C loc_48908C:              # CODE XREF: cgiGetVar+B8j

.text:0048908C             lw      $v1, (dword_4D6A5C - 0x4D0000)($v0) #"ISO-"

.text:00489090             addiu   $v0, (dword_4D6A5C - 0x4D0000)

.text:00489094             lw      $a0, (dword_4D6A60 - 0x4D6A5C)($v0) #"8859"

.text:00489098             swl     $v1, 0($s1)

.text:0048909C             lbu     $a1, (byte_4D6A66 - 0x4D6A5C)($v0)  # zero byte

.text:004890A0             lbu     $a2, (byte_4D6A64 - 0x4D6A5C)($v0)  # "-"

.text:004890A4             lbu     $v0, (byte_4D6A65 - 0x4D6A5C)($v0)  # "1"

.text:004890A8             swr     $v1, 3($s1)

.text:004890AC             swl     $a0, 4($s1)

.text:004890B0             swr     $a0, 7($s1)

.text:004890B4             sb      $a1, 0xA($s1)

.text:004890B8             sb      $a2, 8($s1)

.text:004890BC             b       loc_48A190

.text:004890C0             sb      $v0, 9($s1)

.text:004890C4  #
```

The task I need to solve is, to change Web Language ID from BIG-5 to ISO-8859-5 in my router firmware manager (without sources :) ) So  ISO-8859-5 is 5 letters longer then BIG-5. I've moved the right hand (of BIG-5) text block in .rodata section )here is hex fragment:

```
  4d6a50:   68746d6c 63686172 73657400 49534f2d     htmlcharset.ISO-
  4d6a60:   38383539 2d310000 4249472d 35000000     8859-1..BIG-5...
  4d6a70:   53757043 484c616e 67000000 636f6e6e     SupCHLang...conn
```

& changed the pointer in .text section. However when I run the program it loads just 6 bytes (I see "ISO-88" instead of (ISO-8859-5) in HTML-code page of router. So I guess I have to find where is the number of developing bytes is fixed and change it. Could somebody comments this code. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @plaes Thanks a lot, but these router doesn't like OpenWRT :) It likes vxWorks and ASUS blobs (WMVN25E2plus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of bytes is not specified. It just loads a word and two bytes and that's it:

```
; load one word (4 bytes) into v0
lw      $v0, (aBig5 - 0x4D0000)($v0)
; load one byte into a0
lbu     $a0, (aBig5+5 - 0x4D6A68)($v1)
; load one byte into v1
lbu     $v1, (aBig5+4 - 0x4D6A68)($v1)
; store left part of the word from v0
swl     $v0, 0($s1)
; store right part of the word from v0
swr     $v0, 3($s1)
; store byte from a0
sb      $a0, 5($s1)
; store byte from v1
sb      $v1, 4($s1)
```

So it's basically fixed for a 5-char string and a longer one won't work without patching the code. You *might* be able to patch it for a 7-char one (8 bytes) by loading words and replacing the two `sb` by `swl` and `swr`. Another option, if you are certain that `s1` is aligned, is to load three words (12 bytes) and store the latter two using just `sw` instead of swl/swr pair.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to change sb->swl/swr, but without success :(Could you comment 2-nd part of these code (from 0048908C to down) It contains example of 10 bytes word using. And why is neсessary use swl/swr and sb, when program loads bytes (lbu $v1 (aBig5+5 -0x4D6a68)($v1) ) after loading word (lw)?